# How can I remove an Item from an ArrayList given the itemNum?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, casting

I want to remove the Item given the ItemNo that the user will enter. how do I check if there exists an item with this itemNo first? and how would I then remove it? Below is what I have so far, do I need to add a `CompareTo()` method?

Item Class:

```
public class Item {

public int itemNo;
public String itemName;
public double itemPrice;
public int itemQuantity;

Item(int number, String name, double price, int quantity)
{
itemNo=number;
itemName=name;
itemPrice=price;
itemQuantity=quantity;
}
```

Remove method:

```
 public T remove(int givenPosition) {
     T result = null; 
     if ((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= numberOfEntries)) {
     assert !isEmpty();
     result = list[givenPosition - 1]; 
     if (givenPosition < numberOfEntries)
                  removeGap(givenPosition);
               numberOfEntries--;
     } // end if
     return result; 

         } // end remove
```

Contains Method:

```
 public boolean contains(T anEntry) {
     boolean found = false;
     for (int index = 0; !found && (index < numberOfEntries); index++) {
     if (anEntry.equals(list[index])) 
         found = true;
     }//end for
     return found;
     } // end contains
```

equals Method:

```
public boolean equals(Object object){
        Item item = (Item) object;
        if(itemNo == item.itemNo)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Is `ArrayList` your class or one from `java.util` package?

Comment: You should mark a answer as helpful. Do not leave the question open. Same for your previous questions.

Answer (score 3):

Ok well you are trying to seperate the logic, but I will give you the code snippet for your problem.

```
Item item = new Item(10 , "Item1", 50 , 100);
Item item2 = new Item(20 , "Item2", 50 , 100);
Item item3 = new Item(30 , "Item3", 50 , 100);

List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
itemList.add(item1);
itemList.add(item2);
itemList.add(item3);

public void removeItem(int itemNo){
       Iterator<Item> it = itemList.iterator();
       while(it.hasNext){
         if(item.next().itemNo == itemNo){
            it.remove;
            break;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use an iterator instead of a for loop?

Comment: Iterator for remove is the better option to avoid missing some row or you need to parse the list in the reverse order...

Comment: You will get `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` if you try to add or remove while looping without a iterator

Comment: @MuratK. Only if we are using enhanced-for-loop, simple `for(int i...)` will not throw ConcurrentModificationException. But yes, using Iterator is safer since with simple loop we need to remember about shifting values after removal.

Comment: Oh thanks, I basically stopped using the simple loop for a while ^^

Answer (score 3):

Since Java8 any Collection (like List) have [`removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method which can remove item matching filter. So your code can look like

```
list.removeIf(item -> item.getItemNo() == x );//where x is value you want to remove
```

Comment: I like this answer, very clean. I wasn't aware of this way of removing items either. I assume this will work with Android too?

Comment: @Chackle I am not sure if Java8 was moved to android (I am not android developer so I can't answer it).

Comment: There are some stuff in Java8 which are really cool e.g. this one, but also stuff which will result in some kind of magic code e.g. the lambda notation on listeners. I tried it out, but I still like the old notation.

Comment: @MuratK. Yes, it takes some tome to get used to lambdas and streams introduced in Java 8. Old notation is clean, but new tools gives you possibility of using parallel processing which may be nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void removeObjectWithNumber(int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Item item = list.get(i);
        if (item.getItemNo() == number) {
            list.remove(i);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you'll find his list isn't actually a list, it's an array. Poorly worded question.

Comment: @andybrown you're correct. I guess changing my answer from list.get(i) to list[i] would solve this. Removal however will have to be done another way.

Comment: This will work only if `number` is unique value. If it is not then after removing it elements in list will be shifted so if you will go to next `i++` in next iteration you will skip one element (you will not test it). This means that if there are two `Item`s with same `number` near each other you will skip the second one.

Comment: @pshemo I'm aware of this. The question states how to remove 'an' Item given the itemNum. The question almost assumes unique numbers to be given to the removal method.

Comment: OK, I just wrote it to make it explicit, not necessary for OP but for any reader :)

Comment: @pshemo Yes, thank you for pointing it out :). Might be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList :

Add :

```
ArrayList<Item> mList = new ArrayList<Item>();
mList.add(new Item(101, "Television", 20000, 4));
mList.add(new Item(102, "Mobile", 6000, 4));
```

Remove :

```
mList.remove(i /* index */);
```

Contains :

```
    // override equals method in class
    @Override
  public boolean equals(Object v) {
        boolean retVal = false;

        if (v instanceof A){
            A ptr = (A) v;
            retVal = ptr.itemNo.longValue() == this.itemNo;
            // if you want to check more then you can do
            //  retVal = ptr.itemName.toString().equals(this.itemName.toString());
// further same for itemPrice, itemQuantity
        }

     return retVal;
  }
```